# Conectar UWP C# a MySQL remoto

Tags: c#, json, uwp

**MI CASO**

Estoy intentando conectar mi Aplicación Universal (UWP) a mi sitio Web (PHP) el cual realiza consultas a mi base de datos (MySQL). Los resultados que devuelve PHP son cadenas JSON los cuales tengo que PARSEAR en mi app a través de **JsonObject**.

**LO QUE FUNCIONA**
1. Conexión al sitio Web (ok).
2. Consultas SQL (ok).
3. Devolución de cadenas JSON (ok).

**LOS CÓDIGOS**
Cadenas JSON devueltas por PHP.

```
Modelo A: "{'CAT':'LOG','MSG':'OK','SUBB':{'ID':'U1','USU':'JORNY'}}";  
Modelo B: "{'CAT':'LOG','MSG':'ER','SUBB':'-'}";
```

Función que parsea la cadena JSON en C# (UWP)

```
private async void Consultar(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    /*Capturo los reultados devueltos por PHP*/
    string CadenaJSON = await AccessTheWebAsyncPost();
    /*reemplazo comillas simples por dobles, esta parte lo hago así
      porque C# devuelve error de JSON no válido*/
    string contentLength = CadenaJSON.Replace("'", "\"");
    /*parseo a traves de JsonObject la cadena*/
    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(contentLength);
    /*leo las secciones CAT y SUBB*/
    string sCat = jsonObject["CAT"].GetString();
    string sSubb = jsonObject["SUBB"].GetString();/*<---- El error ocurre aquí*/
    /*muestro los resultados*/
    txtCat.Text = sCat.ToString();
    txtSubb.Text = sSubb.ToString();
}
```

**LO QUE NO FUNCIONA**
1. El parseo de las cadenas JSON funciona muy bien cuando la PHP devuelve modelo B, pero cuando devuelve el modelo A, este manda un error.
Imagino que es porque el modelo A, tien secciones internas dentro de SUBB pero el modelo B no lo tiene.

**EL ERROR**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado a mirar `jsonObject["SUBB"].ValueType` para ver si es un `string` o un array?

Comment: El ValueType devuelve Object

Comment: En ambos casos?

Comment: en CAT sale String en SUBB sale Object cuando uso el modelo A

Comment: Cuando usas el modelo B,deduzco que en SUBB te da String el ValueType? Si es asi, la solucion es comprobar si `jsonObject["SUBB"].ValueType==JsonValueType.String` y en ese caso haces `GetString`,si no `GetArray` o `GetObject`

Comment: Pero como parseo el Object obtenido por getObject

Comment: Puedes hacer algo asi: `string id=jsonObject["SUBB"].GetObject().GetNamedString("ID");` y `string usuario=jsonObject["SUBB"].GetObject().GetNamedString("USU");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por fin pude solucionarlo, gracias al usuario @Pikoh. Publico la solución con el código ya mejorado, espero les sirva. Suerte ;).

```
private async void Consultar(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    /*variables para almacenar secciones de JSON*/
    string sCat = "", sMen = "", sSubb = "";
    string sId  = "", sUsu = "";
    /*Capturar cadena JSON devuelta por PHP*/
    string JsonPHP = await AccessTheWebAsyncPost();
    /*Reemplazar comillas simples por dobles, esto es exigencia de C#*/
    string JsonSharp = JsonPHP.Replace("'", "\"");
    /*Crear objeto Json parseando la cadena JsonSharp*/
    JsonObject objJson = JsonObject.Parse(JsonSharp);
    /*leer secciones del Json*/
    sCat = objJson["CAT"].GetString();
    sMen = objJson["MSG"].GetString();
    /*la seccion SUBB en algunos casos devuelve un JSON interno,
      de ser el caso es un Object, sino, es un String*/
    if (objJson["SUBB"].ValueType == JsonValueType.String)    {
        /*si es un string*/
        sSubb = objJson["SUBB"].GetString();
    }  else  {
        /*si es un object*/
        sId  = objJson["SUBB"].GetObject().GetNamedString("ID"); 
        sUsu = objJson["SUBB"].GetObject().GetNamedString("USU");
    }
    /*mostrar resultado*/
    txtId.Text  = sId.ToString();
    txtUsu.Text = sUsu.ToString();
    /*proceso finalizado*/
    txtEstado.Text = "Proceso finalizado.";
}
```

**DE PASADITA**
Pongo el resto de código, para que lo implementen en sus App UWP con C#

```
async Task<String> AccessTheWebAsyncPost()        {
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    values.Add("VALOR1", "dato_cualquiera");
    values.Add("VALOR2", "dato_cualquiera");
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync("http://sitio.com/prueba.php", content);
    Task<string> getStringTask = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    DoIndependentWork();
    string urlContents = await getStringTask;
    return urlContents.ToString();
}

void DoIndependentWork()  {
    txtEstado.Text = "Consultando...";
}
```

**LA PARTE DEL PHP**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['VALOR1']) and isset($_POST['VALOR2'])){
        $sV1 = $_POST['VALOR1'];
        $sV2 = $_POST['VALOR2'];

        /*devolución de cadena JSON, donde la sección SUBB contiene otro JSON*/
        echo "{'CAT':'LOG','MSG':'OK','SUBB':{'ID':'un_valor','USU':'un_valor'}}";  
        /*devolución de cadena JSON, donde la sección SUBB NO contiene otro JSON*/
        echo "{'CAT':'LOG','MSG':'ER','SUBB':'-'}";
    }
?>
```